# Update with filter on timestamp

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

After somes years without sql oracle activity...I'm trying to update somes status code by date on oracle SQL.
date is in french format DD/MM/YYYY

The format on date_start column is timestamp with this format " 18/10/2019 23:15:26" and i need filter on date -1 month. And working with sqlplus...

i think like this :

```
UPDATE contexte_ihm 
SET set status_code =1000 status_name = (select FLUX_STATUS_NAME from flux_status_ref where FLUX_STATUS_CD=1000)
WHERE status_code=9999 
AND DATE_START = TO_TIMESTAMP( '31/01/2000 08-00-00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24-MI-SS' )
```

i tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM contexte_ihm WHERE status_code =1000 AND DATE_START =to_date('19/12/2019','dd/mm/yyyy')
  2  ;

no rows selected
```

With `<NOW()-30 NOW` is invalid identifier...

I need update 95000 rows from one month ago to older date...

Comment: A date or timestamp doesn't have a format; your client formats the internal representation into something human-readable using your NLS settings by default. And `now()` is not an Oracle function; the equivalent is `sysdate` or `current_date`.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want a range of dates.  I think:

```
WHERE status_code = 9999 AND
      date_start < trunc(sysdate, 'MON') - interval '1 month' and
      date_start >= timestamp '2000-01-31 08:00:00';
```

You should test the `WHERE` clause on a `SELECT` to be sure it gets the right rows.